# What does setAsciiStream do?

Tags: java, jdbc, ascii

Here is the Javadoc

> ```
> void setAsciiStream(int parameterIndex,
>                     InputStream x,
>                     int length)
>                     throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Sets the designated parameter to the given input stream, which will
>   have the specified number of bytes. When a very large ASCII value is
>   input to a `LONGVARCHAR` parameter, it may be more practical to send it
>   via a `java.io.InputStream`. Data will be read from the stream as needed
>   until end-of-file is reached. The JDBC driver will do any necessary
>   conversion from ASCII to the database char format.

I know what an `InputStream` object is. But I still do not understand why would we `set` this `int paramaterindex` to it? The method returns nothing. Does it create an object? What does it transform? Can anybody explain it in simple words?

---

Here is the [API I am talking about](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt)

It has the following lines

> ```
> PreparedStatement pstmtFld 
>     = conFld.prepareStatement(insertTable);
> ...
> pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1);  // What is purpose of this line ???
> pstmtFld.executeUpdate();
> ```

Comment: In suggest you include the API you are talking about.

Comment: Can you clarify what your doubt is as I don't understand what is troubling you about this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I still do not understand why would we set this int paramaterindex to it?

The parameterIndex is the index of the `?` you put in your UPDATE or INSERT statement. Starting at 1.

> The method returns nothing.

setters rarely do.

> Does it create an object?

I imagine it might, but it doesn't have to.

> What does it transform?

Nothing AFAIK. Its a setter.

> Can anybody explain it in simple words?

It sets the parameter assuming you have ASCII text. e.g. if your first parameter is where you want to store text as 8-bit characters, you can use setAsciiText(1, input, -1)

BTW It is very similar to the other methods for this API.  I suggest you look at these for comparison.

Comment: Thank you very much. `The parameterIndex is the index of the ? you put in your UPDATE or INSERT statement. Starting at 1.` does this mean that if I have three columns to upload to the database, and indicate `parameterIndex = 2` then it is going to ignore the first column but create `Ascii` for 2nd and the third?

Comment: @BoratSagddiev For it to work, you have to set 1, 2 and 3 with something.  It doesn't just ignore what you don't set.

Answer (score 2):

As it says, when you have some *very large* piece of data to put in to a database field, you can use this method. It streams the data into the database over the network, instead of loading the entire value into memory in one go, which could be wasteful of memory.

So you would use it like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("huge-file.txt");
BufferedInputStream dataStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1);
```